# How do you install QMK with the new Mac M1 (ARM) chip?

Tags: macos, homebrew, qmk, qmk-firmware

I keep getting compiling errors whenever I follow the Homebrew install guide for QMK.

```
==> Installing qmk from qmk/qmk
avr-gcc@8: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

How can I get this to install correctly?

Comment: To anyone who finds this now before trying to install qmk: this error no longer occurs. You do not need to do anything differently on M1. gcc-avr@8 has been patched to run on M1: https://github.com/osx-cross/homebrew-avr/pull/249

Answer (score 2):

Install Homebrew using Rosetta 2 to do the compilation for you:

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Then, install QMK with the x86_64 arch:

```
arch -x86_64 brew install qmk/qmk/qmk
```

Then follow the rest of the guide from the QMK website: https://beta.docs.qmk.fm/tutorial/newbs_getting_started#3-run-qmk-setup-id-set-up-qmk.

Comment: Error: Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!
To rerun under ARM use:
    arch -arm64 brew install ...
To install under x86_64, install Homebrew into /usr/local.

Comment: Did you install homebrew first?

Comment: ```echo 'eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"' >>  $HOME/.zprofile && eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"``` before ```brew install```

Comment: The link is broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at beta.docs.qmk.fm."*

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can fix it? Or suggest what it should be changed to?

Answer (score 1):

I use Docker (Podman actually, but both works) as the container can be amd64 with Rosetta and Podman (there is a solution for Docker too).

Then I build an image like that, and I run inside the container (I override the default keyboard layout with mine, so that I don't have to create a user).

When you run it, mount a volume from your machine as '/output' and copy the bin or do a `podman/docker copy`.

```
FROM docker.io/qmkfm/base_container:latest
RUN pip install qmk && \
    qmk setup -y -H /qmk_firmware
WORKDIR /qmk_firmware
COPY keymap/keymap.c /qmk_firmware/keyboards/novelkeys/nk65/keymaps/default/keymap.c
COPY config/qmk/qmk.ini /root/.config/qmk/qmk.ini

# Make Bash as the default command
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: I like this approach - clean and developer friendly. Going to give it a go today!

Answer (score 0):

Error: Cannot install under Rosetta 2 in ARM default prefix (*/opt/homebrew*)!

To rerun under ARM, use:

```
arch -arm64 brew install ...
```

To install under x86_64, install Homebrew into */usr/local*.